# Is there a way that I can disable change password

Tags: password, users

I have 20 computers in a high school lab and I want to set up a standard student log in. This is done, the problem is that students can change the password to anything, is there a way to block this? thanks.

Comment: Can you be more explicit. About what password do you speak? "password to anything" doesn't sound clear for me.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Vincent is saying users can change the password to any arbitrary password, thus other students can not log in. A sort of DOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the -n option

> -n, --mindays MIN_DAYS
>
> Set the minimum number of days between password changes to
>   MIN_DAYS. A value of zero for this field indicates that the user
>   may change his/her password at any time.

So

```
sudo passwd <user> -n 10000
```

See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/man1/passwd.1.html