# What should I do to avoid my roommate from changing my password through using system recovery mode .?

Tags: grub2, password, security, root

He did this last time when I left my laptop at room. Opened the system recovery mode from advanced Ubuntu options and changed the password using 'passwd usrname ' command.Is there anything I can do for this to not happen in future.

Comment: you can kill him. 
joking, possible duplicated of http://askubuntu.com/questions/303654/is-there-a-way-that-i-can-disable-change-password

Comment: Heh. This is actually a cool trick. It works for Macs too. I have heard about setting root password, but that causes all sorts of problems in a system. ||| @Geo : Not a dupe at all. That is in regards to not allowing password-setting in Multiuser mode (booted). Root can override that restriction, so it wouldn't help here, nor is it a dupe.

Comment: @Mew what problems does it cause?

Comment: @muru Makes it easier to brute-force your system, adds challenges for you, makes hackers think what you're hiding, and causes a few SSH vulnerabilities. (Had a server). Sudo is much safer/easier, but it does allow this *feature*.

Comment: @Mew What need to brute force if there is no password? SSH by default disallows password authentication for root. Adds only one challenge for the user: remember two passwords.

Comment: @muru True, all I know is that my server was brought down because my root account had a password. Stupid SSH bug probably. You can't put faith into code being perfect. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent someone from resetting my password with a Live CD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/76987/how-can-i-prevent-someone-from-resetting-my-password-with-a-live-cd) (The considerations and solutions are almost all the same, and the goal is probably to prevent access via recovery mode *and* via a live environment.) @Geo [That's](http://askubuntu.com/questions/303654/is-there-a-way-that-i-can-disable-change-password) about preventing a non-root user from changing their password in the normal way while the system is already running.

Answer (score 0):

For this user case probably the best "solution" is to re-install Ubuntu with full encryption (LUKS). This would secure the data and prevent changing the  root/users password(s).

This could be defeated with a few methods, both hardware (key loggers) and software (custom kernels), but both of those options are unlikely. The OP can assess these risks.

With the above suggestion, I agree with the advice that the ultimate solution is to prevent physical access. In general physical access is root access via any number of techniques.

Comment: This is too much effort to deter pranks.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Set the root password. Open a terminal, and do:

```
sudo passwd
```

Enter a password. Then the root shell in recovery mode will always ask for this password.

Note that all this is futile as he can boot into a live USB and change your password.

Ultimately, given physical access, the security battle is lost.

Comment: Block LiveCDs? *goes into BIOS* | Block BIOS? *opens computer and gets HDD* | Locked-In HDD? *unlocks using lockpicking kit and screwdriver* | Encrpyed HDD? *cat \dev\null > \dev\sdb*. Always a way to do SOMETHING with physical access. My HS tech guy and I would have wars over who could do the worst damage with only physical access.

Comment: Also, you're forgetting about Hirens Boot CD. It has a tool to bypass passwords now.

Comment: @Mew Doesn't prevent anyone from quickly removing the hard disk, attaching elsewhere and doing whatever they want. And adds yet another password for the user to remember. Let me repeat: physical access, the battle is lost. However, for low-grade fun like this roommate, setting a root password is enough, and simplest.

Comment: I agree, setting a root password as muru advised is worthless and adds no significant additional security.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I disagree, since this is enough to deter the casual prank. Anything more is a sledgehammer to kill an ant. While security is important, the context in which this security is setup is also important. Average users don't care. Otherwise we'd all be using full-disk encryption and BIOS passwords and unique passwords for everything, and encrypt all communication.

Comment: We will have to agree to disagree. As has been pointed out to you by other users, resetting the root password is rather trivial.